# PHP - String Clean

Tags: php, string

I'm starting a comment system for my website.  The problem is I want to use an HTML editor, but is not fully necessary.

My problem is with the security.  How to secure the user input that I save in database? Because I show that input on my website and I want to prevent XSS, SQL Injection and other things like that. But I still want my users to be able to write any characters.

For example, daniweb uses and HTML EDITOR (wysiwyg .

I also tried

```
function bstring( $value )
{
    $value = htmlentities( $value, ENT_QUOTES );
    $value = strip_tags( $value );
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
    return (string)$value;
}
```

Comment: PDO, prepared statements.. google that. HTML escaping is done when you *retrieve*. That way you have the original in your db and can manipulate it at will.

Comment: Using `htmlentities` and `strip_tags` together like that will not work.  `strip_tags` will not find any tags to strip, since they have been encoded by `htmlentities`.  Plus `mysql_real_escape_string` is *completely* useless for displaying a string to the user.  You want to use prepared statements (with MySQLi/PDO) to insert into the db.  When you display it to the user, you can just simply use `htmlspecialchars` (or `htmlentities`) by itself.

Comment: Use `PDO` that is intended to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php)
you can use this:

```
$mysqli->real_escape_string($value);
```

It

> *Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement*

Comment: If you use MySQLi, you *should* be using prepared statements.  There's almost no reason that you'd ever need to use `real_escape_string`.

Comment: I don't understand the benefit of prepared statements over `real_escape_string`. Can you explain?

Comment: And this does NOT protect agains his mentioned XSS. Only against SQL injection!

Comment: @AndiPower: There are countless benefits.  The biggest being that you no longer need to use `real_escape_string` and you no longer need to worry about quotes/apostrophes.  It's safer, future-proof, and the recommended way now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the user to input HTML tags but disallow him to use certain tags like Scripts, you should just implement some form of whitelisting for tags.

```
$allowed_tags = "<b><i><br>"; // Some safe examples
$value = strip_tags( $value, $allowed_tags );
```

Allways know when and why to use which filter:

- **mysql_real_escape_string** - Protects your SQL against injection - Allways needed if no connector with proper parameter binding is used
- **strip_tags** - Removes unwanted tags from unsafe output you show on your page. Can be used to counter XSS attacks - See above
- **htmlspecialchars** - Encode html tags so that they will no longer work. Protects agains XSS but also removes HTML functionality - You dont want this as you actually want users to use HTML tags

Comment: Someone told me that strip_tags, mysql_real_escape_string and htmlspecialchars does not do the job.

Comment: That is wrong. Like I said, you have to understand what to filter and why.

Comment: What do you think about: strip, then specialchars, then real escape and then html purifier?

Comment: I think that is unecessry. strip does the job against XSS if your whitelist is well thought out (easy!). real escape does the job against SQL Injections. special chars would break your users html so it's not usable here and purify is just some form of cosmetic, also unecessary (and a big performance impact).

Answer (score 0):

htmlentities doesnt provides security

you need to strip  the html  using  replace
following a list  what tags you want to forbid and what tags you want to allow

```
 function  bstring($str){

    //forbid your tags here
   $forbidden_tags = array('script', 'body', 'html');


   for($i = 0; $i < count($forbidden_tags); $i++){

        $tag = '%<'.$forbidden_tags[$i].'.*?</'.$forbidden_tags[$i].'>%i';

        $result = preg_replace($tag, 'NOT ALLOWED', $str);

   }



   return $result;




 }
```

Comment: This could work, but since php's regex has problems with recursive tags and you also have to safe guard against unclosed and non standard tags with properties, this is a HELL of a lot of work.

Comment: Just no. I want that things for a wysiwyg editor, i want to keep the bold, i, and other tags from CKeditor but secure all things from sqli and xss

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Doctrine**:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_%28PHP%29

One of Doctrine's key features is the option to write database queries in a proprietary object oriented SQL dialect called Doctrine Query Language (DQL). Actual SQL queries are generated by Doctrine only (that would protect from SQL Injection and other things like that).

official site: http://www.doctrine-project.org/

read this about security:  http://www.doctrine-project.org/2014/02/21/security_in_doctrine.html

Comment: Does not protected against XSS, it's only safe against SQL injections. Remember, he WANTS users to use HTML tags, just not all of them.

Comment: Well, nothing would stop him to combine several things. For example he can strip tags, like you suggested, and then pass values to doctrine. Undeserved negative vote, btw....

Comment: You are right, that's why I didnt downvote you. Still, his main question was for SQL and XSS, not only one of it.